# Upload an .ipa to apple store using macintouch

Tags: ios, mobile

i have build a mobile application, i tested on iphone using developer certificate
it works fine on that device

I want to upload to app store  but i discovered that my windows can not do that

i found a server online: macintouch that can help me with that

Pls can anyone help to acheive this OR

use the server please tell me is the server good

macintouch: is the server good to use for upload to appstore

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about macintouch server but you need either Xcode or Application Loader to upload ipa to AppStore. May be you can try installing one on them into your server.
 [See this for instruction for uploading from xcode.](https://instabug.com/blog/how-to-submit-app-to-app-store/)

There is also some software (available for windows) which will help you to upload ipa to AppStore. But I haven't used, so am not sure, you get succeed or not but you can try. [Example app](http://www.applicationloader.net/blog/en/888.html?gclid=EAIaIQobChMIrNi26ey74gIVUuR3Ch304gbMEAAYASAAEgJgSPD_BwE)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification